# dynamic class creation in groovy

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I am new in Groovy, started this to try meta-programming in Groovy. I want to create classes dynamically based on user input and one class can have a member variable of another type that has been created dynamically. For example, 
1. Create a class called "Name" with member variables "firstName" of type String and "lastName" of type String
2. Create class called "User" with a member variable "name" of type "Name" (that has been created in step 1)
The idea is, user can define any type for which the classes will be created

I was able to create class dynamically using "SimpleTemplateEngine". It is working fine when I am creating a class with member variables of types that are already defined. If I create a class where a member variable is of another dynamic class type then it is not working. It would be great if I can get some help on this.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic class creation? the code ? compiled class? the instance? could you share your code?

Comment: I meant to say the code to create a class which will be compiled and load in a classloader at runtime. Based on user input I will create the code which will in-turn create and load the class at runtime

Answer (score -1):

I am able to resolve this issue. Initially I was creating both the classes dynamically and was loading using different class loaders and because of that User class was complaining about class not found for the "Name" class. After using the same classloader for both the classes the issue is resolved.